# Nav tabs not working correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create this nav bars with Bootstrap on my website but I am not sure why I want menu 5 to show only Tokyo is the capital of Japan but apparently, the other items from menu 2 are still showing, I have been on this for a while, not sure what's wrong. I have also checked my divs to ensure proper closing. I am a newbie at this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="infoBox">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu5">Menu 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id = "home" class="tab-pane fade in active" >
                </div>

                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Query by Placename Name</h1>
                        <p>Query</p>
                        <p>
                            <b>Select Overlay Map</b>
                        </p>

                        <select name="Layerchoice" id="select1" onchange="dropdown_onchange(this)">
                            <option value="dummy" disabled  selected>Please select</option>
                            <option value="OSM">Testlayer1</option>
                            <option value="stamen">Testlayer2</option>
                        </select>

                        <div>
                            <input name="scalecheck"  value="1" type="checkbox">Map Scale
                            <div id = "radio" class="buttons">
                                <input type="radio" name="scale" id="linearcheck">Linear Scale<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="scale" id="bettercheck">Alternating Scale Bar<br/>
                            </div>
                            <div id= "layercontrol" >
                                <button type="button" id="button-basemap1" onclick="togglePoints();"> Basemap 1</button>
                                <input type="checkbox" id= "layercontrol2"  />Base Map<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleSatellite();" />Satellite<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleLabels();" />Labels<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleTraffic();" />Traffic<br />
                            </div> 
                        </div> 

                        <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <div>
                                <h1>Tokyo</h1>
                                <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to correctly open/close your divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your last menu div in the wrong place

Move the menu5 div down two levels:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="infoBox">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu5">Menu 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id = "home" class="tab-pane fade in active" >
                </div>

                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Query by Placename Name</h1>
                        <p>Query</p>
                        <p>
                            <b>Select Overlay Map</b>
                        </p>

                        <select name="Layerchoice" id="select1" onchange="dropdown_onchange(this)">
                            <option value="dummy" disabled  selected>Please select</option>
                            <option value="OSM">Testlayer1</option>
                            <option value="stamen">Testlayer2</option>
                        </select>

                        <div>
                            <input name="scalecheck"  value="1" type="checkbox">Map Scale
                            <div id = "radio" class="buttons">
                                <input type="radio" name="scale" id="linearcheck">Linear Scale<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="scale" id="bettercheck">Alternating Scale Bar<br/>
                            </div>
                            <div id= "layercontrol" >
                                <button type="button" id="button-basemap1" onclick="togglePoints();"> Basemap 1</button>
                                <input type="checkbox" id= "layercontrol2"  />Base Map<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleSatellite();" />Satellite<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleLabels();" />Labels<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleTraffic();" />Traffic<br />
                            </div> 
                        </div> 

                        
                    </div> 
                  
                </div> 
                 <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
                     <div>
                       <h1>Tokyo</h1>
                       <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
                     </div>
                 </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```